# MongoDB Docker container start and then exits itself with non Docker error codes

Tags: mongodb, docker, ubuntu, ubuntu-18.04

I have 3 containers, Ubuntu 18.04 with some softwares, mongodb and cassandra.
I'm able to start Ubuntu normally, but when I try to start mongodb it exits itself right after the start.

I checked /var/lib and there is no docker directory over there, so I ran `docker container logs mongodb > logMongodb.log` and this show up(took only the end of it): https://pastebin.com/riHDKBEy

This line cought my attention:

```
 {"t":{"$date":"2020-09-30T14:55:39.882+00:00"},"s":"E",  "c":"STORAGE",  "id":20568,   "ctx":"initandlisten","msg":"Error setting up listener","attr":{"error":{"code":9001,"codeName":"SocketException","errmsg":"Permission denied"}}}
```

But I don't knnow exactly what it means and how to fix it...

Answer (score 0):

you should try an other tag for your mongodb image. it work for me with the focal tag

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).